# Jquery IF statement and .is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i wanted to do something after a JQUERY have successfully run,

```
var Public =  $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(classes).css({"background-color": "yellow"});
      if($(this).is(Public)){
          CountPub = CountPub + 1;
          console.log(CountPub);
      }
```

### This code should works as the following:

1) invoke a element with the colour yellow if the selector is correct
2) increase the counter by 1 everytime it has successfully invoked the css scripts

Comment: try `Public.get()`. `Public` is a jQuery object and `this` is an HTMLElement

Comment: what is `this`? You need to provide more code context

Comment: @jona, are you trying to do this: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/78ws4yjj/)**

Comment: @Rajesh sorry if i didn't ask my question clearly, initially i wanted to do something similiar to your codes, which increase the counter if it runs the css codes (without clicking), but it seems that the 2 answer below solved my problem without going through the hassle of examining whether the codes have been executed or not, thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be all you need, just counting the number of elements that match the selector by using `length` of resultant collection

```
var Public =  $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(classes).css({"background-color": "yellow"});

var CountPub = Public.length
```

Comment: this works well, but can i know what's the difference between this and @bram vanroy answer!

thank you very much!

Comment: This solution iterates behind the scenes (which is possible and even recommended with jQuery). So basically what it does is find all elements matching the selector, put them in a variable while assigning a yellow background to them. When that's done, find the size of the elements in the variable. This solution is the one to use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to do this:

```
var CountPub = 0;
$("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(classes).each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  CountPub++;
});
```